# How to Start Admin console webpage through Linux command in websphere?

Tags: websphere

I have a question that can we start admin console browser through Linux command prompt. If yes, How?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed the admin console as part of the application server installation process, you merely need to start the server and then open a browser to the URL for the console (see this IBM [TechNote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21155098) for assistance in figuring out that URL)
If for example you are using firefox and it's on your path, something like this:

```
firefox http://hostname:9060/ibm/console
```